# how to create temporary div and remove everything except the first image jquery

Tags: jquery, html, json, temporary

I'm trying to develop mobile app with jquery mobile for my webpage. I get the content in json format whatever the topic is I want to get to create temporary div with jquery when I will place description value which I get from JSON feed and I want to get only first image tag from that div and output it along the item title. This is what I have:

```
   function artikujt(data)
{
    console.log(data.query.results.item[0]);
    var path = data.query.results; //vendodhja e array-it me artikuj
    var output = '<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">';
    var id = '';
    var temp = '';
    $.each (path.item,function(key,val){
        id_temp= val.guid.content.replace(/[^0-9 ]/g, '');
        //id=val.guid.content.replace('^\d');
        id= id_temp.substring(0,4);
        var tempDiv = '<div id="tempDiv"' + val.description + '</div>';
        temp = $('#tempDiv').find('img:first');
        output+='<li>';
        output+='<a href="#blogpost" onclick="showPost('+ id +')">';
        output+='<p>' + temp + '</p>';
        output+='<h3 style="word-wrap:break-word;">'+ val.title +'</h3>';
        output+='<p>ID: ' + id + '</p>';
        output+='</a>';
        output+='</li>';
        //console.log(val.title);
    });
    output+='</ul>';
    $('#shfaqLajmet').html(output);

}
```

From that val.description I want to remove all content except the first image tag which is there inside the description. Whith these code I got **[object Object]** message only

EDIT:

my HTML:
This is the div where I display the results:

```
<div data-role="content" id="shfaqLajmet"> 
     <!-- Lajmet ne faqen kryesore -->
 </div>
<script src='https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20feed%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Ffeeds.feedburner.com%2Fradio-pendimi%2FVpZJ%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=artikujt'></script>
```

Comment: Can you add your HTML?

Comment: @j809 [code]<div data-role="content" id="shfaqLajmet"> 
     <!-- Lajmet ne faqen kryesore -->
 </div>
and this is the script link to fetch JSON feed
[code]<script src='https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20feed%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Ffeeds.feedburner.com%2Fradio-pendimi%2FVpZJ%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=artikujt'></script>

Comment: Add it to you post, it is impossible otherwise, also you can add a JSON response example so that is easier for us..

Comment: Yes I got it I'm new to stackoverflow so I'm not very informed for the things how they are going on my apologies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `$('#tempDiv')` because the div with that ID hasn't been added to the DOM yet (nor is it even an element yet, so jQuery will never find it).

So now, if `val.description` is HTML, you might wrap it up in a jQuery object (to actually create the DOM element) and *then* use `.find()` to pull out the image part:

```
var tempDiv = $('<div id="tempDiv">' + val.description + '</div>');
temp = tempDiv.find("img:first");
...
output += '<p>' + $('<div>').append(temp).html() + '</p>';
```

Also, you have a typo:

```
var tempDiv = '<div id="tempDiv"' + val.description + '</div>';
                                ^ no closing angle bracket
```

Comment: You're welcome. I would also suggest looking into a JavaScript templating engine (underscore, mustache, handlebars, etc.), because manually building HTML is quite cumbersome and hard to maintain.

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
$("#someId").find("img").first();
```

Comment: same result [object Object]

Comment: Won't work neither. The `div` is not added to the DOM so it's not findable.